# Can the Service endpoint be made accessible to all the projects in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am creating Whitesource endpoint in VSTS. Currently, I need to create a new point for every project in the build task.

[image]

How can I make this endpoint accessible to all the projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, there is no way to add endpoints across all projects. And the added endpoint can be used for a certain project now.

And this is an user voice [VSTS: add services on project collection level](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/11701410-vsts-add-services-on-project-collection-level) which suggest this feature, you can vote and follow up.